# testnet.blockchain.info api not showing latest results?

Tags: blockchain.info, api, testnet

I sent a transaction to the testnet address **mzWCWQU6phb9rKSAiQ4FBU92sGYtY7tjPH** a few days ago and I have been using the testnet.blockchain.info api for a while now in my project.
It was working fine last month but now it doesn't seem to be getting the latest transactions.

This is the api call:

https://testnet.blockchain.info/multiaddr?active=mzWCWQU6phb9rKSAiQ4FBU92sGYtY7tjPH

and this is the same address on Blockcypher:

https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/address/mzWCWQU6phb9rKSAiQ4FBU92sGYtY7tjPH/

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a few weeks ago that the URL https://testnet.blockchain.info now redirects to the main BTC/BCH/ETH explorer page. The whole site has a new look, and new coins.

If you search for the address via the web interface, you can see the testnet transaction: https://www.blockchain.com/btctest/address/mzWCWQU6phb9rKSAiQ4FBU92sGYtY7tjPH

Given the recent changes, is it possible they just haven't yet changed over the API for testnet?